# String in a XML

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am wondering why when I write this in the URL:
http://ServerNameRedacted/IISHostedCalcService/FilesService.svc/GetFoldersAndFiles?selectedFolder=FOLDER//SUBFOLDER

I can't get the information in XML.

But when I use this, the parameter in my function which is exactly the same thing FOLDER//SUBFOLDER it doesn't work...

If I write it directly in a string it will work. So I don't know why, because the parameter is exactly the same...

Should I use string.format or something?

```
    void listBoxFolders_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
      
        Folder directory = new Folder();


        directory = (Folder)listBoxFolders.SelectedItem;
              
        
        // Connexion to the webservice to get the subfolders and also the files
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadSubFoldersAndFiles);
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://myserver.net/IISHostedCalcService/FilesService.svc/GetFoldersAndFiles?selectedFolder=" + directory.FullPath.Substring(25) + '/'));
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you're adding a forward slash at the end of the URI in your code, I would submit that they are not, in fact, the same.

Create your URI string outside of the `DownloadStringAsync` method, and use a  a `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` to see what the actual contents are of your URI string.

Comment: Fixed... That was exactly the problem .. My mistake.